# Failed to fetch the following dependencies: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am using **Unity 2019.3.6f1** and **Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v5.0.1**. I have imported the plugin to my Unity editor. When I try to resolve, error message appear and ask to look at console. Message at  console **"Failed to fetch the following dependencies: com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.0.0"**. This is my third time making game using unity but first time happen to me. Hope anyone can give me idea what is happening and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*Can you confirm that you have the externs.cpp file in Assets/Plugins/Android (included in the Google Mobile Ads Unity package) and that it is checked for inclusion in Android builds, as per below?*"

[image: Tick Android]

Answer taken from Issue in v5.0.1. See [this](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/1208).

Comment: Yes I have that extern file and Android was ticked. I also try to downgrade my plugin to v4.2.1 according link you gave but still cannot resolve.

Comment: Update: It solved! I need to delete all imported assets from v5.0.1 first. Then import v4.2.1. Thanks for your help!